# CalculatedMember formula ignores current query context

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

Pentaho 5.1.2.1.137

I have defined a Dimension with a Hierarchy that contains 3 Levels: Enterprise, Division, Store.
In my cube I have a CalculatedMember that counts the number of Stores for the current member of this hierarchy. It looks like this:

```
<CalculatedMember name="Store count" dimension="Measures">
  <Formula>Count(Descendants([Location.Location].CurrentMember, [Store]))</Formula>
</CalculatedMember>
```

...and this works fine until...

I try to generate a report where I set a filter of 'Division includes Division 1'.
This works if the report contains columns for Enterprise, Division and Store count, but not if the report only contains columns for Enterprise and Store count. In that case, the Store count gets set to 0 even though there are 5 stores in Division 1.

I can't figure out how to make the formula take the current query context into account (if this is indeed the problem).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You query won't hit `Division`, because in your formula you refer to `[Location.Location].CurrentMember` which means if there is no `Division` level specified on other axis, you won't get result.

You can modify formula to always use lowest level and also add EXISTING keyword, which will force server to use current filtering context:

```
Count(EXISTING [Location.Location].[Store].members)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately using 'existing' generates a MondrianException with the version of Pentaho in use. (That's probably why 'existing' doesn't appear in the Pentaho docs.)

Comment: Check this link http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?82955-MDX-quot-EXISTING-quot-Keyword-Need-Syntax-Help